# The best way to use tcpdump in schedule

Tags: ubuntu, cron, tcpdump

I'm a new user for linux and now I have a mission for capture packets in a specific time.

For example, I want to capture packets and then save it to pcap file(every file limit 50mb). I can use this command :

```
tcpdump -C 50 -w mypackets.pcap
```

But I don't know how to run this in a specific period time.
For example, run this on every Mon to Fri (And the period is 2019/02/01 ~ 2019/02/28)
After 2019/02/28 , this process will be killed.

I have read [the doc](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) , but there seems no parameter to control this option

Is there any good idea to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to schedule when processes run, then you might want to look into [crontab](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).

For example, the following cron jobs will cause `tcpdump` to be started every Monday and terminated every Friday:

```
$ crontab -e
o
0    0    *    *    mon   tcpdump -C 50 -w mypackets.pcap
0    0    *    *    sat   killall -s SIGINT tcpdump
ESC:wq
crontab: installing new crontab
```

Alternatively, if you just want to capture for an entire month, March for example, then you could use something like this instead:

```
$ crontab -e
o
0    0    1    mar  *   tcpdump -C 50 -w mypackets.pcap
0    0    1    apr  *   killall -s SIGINT tcpdump
ESC:wq
crontab: installing new crontab
```

You will need to manually remove the cron jobs when you no longer need them.  Be sure to test your cron jobs before you actually need them to run so you know they'll work as expected when you really need them.

You might also want to look into using [`dumpcap`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/dumpcap.html) instead of `tcpdump`, as `dumpcap` allows you to specify that capturing be stopped after a specified number of seconds with the **-a duration:value** option, so you wouldn't necessarily need to explicitly stop it because it will terminate itself after that amount of time has passed.